# Phalcon Micro application. Redirect is not working

Tags: php, redirect, phalcon

https://gist.github.com/mrspartak/790eddb6619aff75634b

So this code is not redirecting when I access to / path. Is there any thoughts about why?

Comment: What does it do instead? Is it safe to say that "$app->session->has("logged_in")" evaluates to true?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. Have you find a solution?

[UPDATE - SOLUTION]

Check this code out: https://github.com/cmoore4/phalcon-rest/blob/develop/index.php

I've solved using the same logic of the commented begin handler in the above code. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect is not working properly because you did not send proper headers. Referring to Phalcon documentation page no. 289, your code needed to be modified like this :-

```
$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router();
$app->before(function() use ($app, $router) {
 if($app->session->has("logged_in") !== true && $router->getRewriteUri() != '/login') {
    $app->response->redirect("login")->sendHeaders();
    return false;
 }
});
```

I added the second condition in the if-statement just to check if the user has requested the "login" page or has been redirected to the "login" page then he shouldn't be redirected again.

Answer (score 0):

Rather remove slash in front of login:

```
$app->get('login', function () use ($app) {
   echo '/login'; 
});
```